# Touch Event Not Triggering on Mobile Device

Tags: javascript, events, handler, delegation, touchstart

I am developing functionality for a website where users can click the screen (a star with a rating next to it) and it will send a call to the backend to like users' stories and also update the front end value displayed on the web page. All of that has been successful using a 'click' event.

After soft-launching my site, I realize that with a touch screen mobile device this functionality has ceased to work. I have scoured the internet for answers, but have found nothing quite clear, on why my new 'touchstart' isn't working on mobile. Here is my client-side javascript:

```
//HANDLER FUNCTIONS FOR EVENT/////////////////////////
const increaseValue = (postID) => {
    let ratingValue = parseInt(
        document.getElementById(`${postID}--rating`).innerHTML
    );
    // UPDATES RATING VALUE ON THE FRONT END
    ratingValue += 1;
    document.getElementById(`${postID}--rating`).innerHTML = ratingValue;
};

const likePost = (event) => {
    // EVENT DELEGATION
    let postID = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
    if (postID) {
        increaseValue(postID);
        // SENDS TO EXPRESS ROUTE TO UPDATE RATING IN DATABASE
        increaseRating(postID); //imported function to route to backend
    }
};

// EVENT LISTENERS //////////////////////////////////
// Increase Posts Rating EVENT HANDLER for Home Page
if (document.querySelector('.event-delegation-1')) {
    document
        .querySelector('.event-delegation-1')
        .addEventListener('touchstart', likePost, false);
    document
        .querySelector('.event-delegation-1')
        .addEventListener('click', likePost, false);
} else {
    console.log('kaw');
}
```

Here is a snippet of HTML:

```
 <!-- Main Content -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto event-delegation-1">
          <% for (var i = 0; i < blogposts.length; i++) { -%>
          <div class="post-preview" id="<%=blogposts[i]._id%>">
            <a href="/posts/<%= blogposts[i]._id %>">
              <h2 class="post-title">
                <%= blogposts[i].title %>
              </h2>
              <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                <%- limitStory(blogposts[i].body) %>
              </h3>
            </a>
            <p class="post-meta">
              Posted by
              <a href="/users/profile/<%=blogposts[i].userid.username%>"
                ><%= blogposts[i].userid.username %>,
                <%=blogposts[i].userid.role %></a
              >
              <%= blogposts[i].datePosted.toDateString() %>
            </p>
            <div class="rating-system d-inline-flex align-items-center">
              <!--  <a href="#"> -->
              <svg
                id="<%=blogposts[i].title%>--star"
                class="bi bi-star-fill"
                width="1em"
                height="1em"
                viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                fill="currentColor"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.283.95l-3.523 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z"
                />
              </svg>
              <!--   </a> -->
              <div
                class="rating-system__blog-score ml-2"
                id="<%=blogposts[i]._id%>--rating"
              >
                <%= blogposts[i].rating %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr />
          ...
```

Any advice would be welcomed regarding this topic. I believe it has something to do with the event listeners, but I can't make heads or tails of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the the code you supplied there is no way of knowing if likePost will ever call increaseValue. You're stacking 3 times parentNode but in your html example the event target only has 2 ancestors.

So try logging the postID in likePost immediately after registrering the variable.

You can also try adding an eventlistener for touchstart on the document itself to see if that will trigger. If not you have another underlying issue.

Comment: Thanks for helping, the parentNode goes up three times because the action is being taken on the <path> element I believe, and travels up to the <div id='blogpost[i]._id'>. I am logging all events now, and it seems to be that touch/mouse are registering, of course, I'm developing on a desktop.

Comment: You are not registrering the event on the <path> element. Your are registrering it on the '.event-delegation-1' selector, which wraps almost the entire thing. Try changing '.event-delegation-1' to '.event-delegation-1 path' or just '.event-delegation-1 svg' and remove 1 of the parentNode iterations.
You can log event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode or just event.target to check if you're actually dealing with the elements you think you are.

Instead of stacking parentNodes you could also loop the ancestors until you find the id.

Answer (score 0):

I think `touchend` might be closer to the `click` handler, because you need to detect when they finish tapping.

Also, try add `console.log(event)` to your `likePost` function to see what the actual events are being triggered. It might be that the target is not what you expect.

Also try adding `event.preventDefault()` to that function, because it may be that the events are bubbling and triggering on other elements and reversing things at the same time.